# Mailto is not loading the subject(or body);

Tags: javascript, html

I have been reading a lot of topics and trying for some time now and i can't seem to get my mailto: to fill in my subject and body.

So it starts the mail-client (i have tried 3 different clients(outlook,windows standard,gmail) and every time it fills in the mail-address but never the subject and body.

```
totalmenu() {
var form = document.getElementById('emailform');
// form.action = "mailto:" + personeel.email + "?subject=result&body=" 
//+ mail();
form.action = "mailto:blabla@gmail.com?Subject=result;
}
```

The comment shows the actual mailto i wanted to use. 
I made a new  mailto with only a subject  to check if it was object related but this is not working as well. 
any of u guys had similar problems or maybe see what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It works perfectly for me - pasting `mailto:blabla@gmail.com?Subject=result` in the address bar and Allowing composes an email with subject.

Comment: so it  is computer related? not code

Comment: Keep in mind, that "mailto:" is a very old fashioned, mostly unstandardized and unreliable technique, because your (and more importantly your users') browser and mail client have to be setup correctly. Plus this is a spam magnet for the email address. You really should consider using "normal" form that posts to a server-side script which then sends out the email from the server (oder better don't send an email, but simply store the message on the server.)

Comment: I have to agree with @RoToRa but it is still nice to know what caused the problem.

Comment: thank for explaining!  i already figured out that this is not the way i am  suppose to work in the future. but  i'm still first year student  and we have not seen server side.  still i need to make a mail work for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build my own little test code, and probably found what the problem is. This code seems to work:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="emailform" method="POST">
  <input type="text" value="this is a test">
  <input type="submit" value="send email">
</form>
<script>
(function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('emailform');
  form.action = "mailto:blabla@example.com?Subject=result";
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I change the form method from `"POST"` to `"GET"` it doesn't work anymore.

Are you using `"GET"`?

I tested the code with Firefox and Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: this solves  the problem! i did not add a method  to my form in html(i guess it takes GET as standard method) . never knew this was necessary! thanks for your time!  i appreciate it allot